# Product of positive definite matrices not itself positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about the following proof.  I'm pretty sure it's incorrect, but I can't figure out why, perhaps you guys can help me figure it out:

Given $A$ and $B$ which are symmetric, positive-definite $N \times N$ matrices, I want to prove that the product $AB$ itself is positive-definite.  As positive-definiteness is defined by the quadtratic form, I start with that:
$$
x^T AB x > 0
$$

I know I can expand $x$ as a weighted sum of eigenvectors of $B$, so I'll start by doing that.  Assuming that $v_{B_i}$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_{B_i}$ and $w_{B_i}$ is the respective weight necessary to satisfy:
$$
x = \sum_{i=0}^N w_{B_i} v_{B_i}
$$

I can represent my quadratic form as:
$$
x^T A B (\sum_{i=0}^N w_{B_i} v_{B_i}) \\
= x^T A (\sum_{i=0}^N \lambda_{B_i} w_{B_i} v_{B_i})
$$

Now I can do the same trick to my already expanded eigenvectors for $A$:
$$
x^T A (\sum_{i=0}^N \lambda_{B_i} w_{B_i} (\sum_{j=0}^N w_{B_i,~ A_j} v_{A_j}))
$$

Where $w_{B_i,~ A_j}$ represents the weight needed for each eigenvector $v_{A_j}$ of $A$ to represent the $x$ that has passed through $B$.

Therefore, since all $\lambda$ terms are positive, we're going to have an $x$ that passed through both $A$ and $B$ that was amplified by both, and the resulting $x$ (if I were to perform the same expansion via both eigenbases) when dotted with this "transformed" $x$ would result in a positive number.  Therefore, $AB$ is positive definite for all $x$.

So my question is, where is this proof going wrong?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should write out the steps in your second last paragraph and see if they actually work.